# Two network interfaces access from the third subnet

Tags: linux, networking, routing, gateway, nic

I faced the following problem. There is server (Ubuntu 12.04) with two NIC that have IPs 192.168.40.147 (eth0) in 192.168.40.128/27 subnet and 192.168.40.165 (eth1) in 192.168.40.160/27 subnet. Now we have the following routing table on server:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.40.160  *               255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.40.128  *               255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.40.161  0.0.0.0         UG    99     0        0 eth1
default         192.168.40.129  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

I try to ping both server IPs from 192.168.32.69 in 192.168.32.1/23 subnet and can do it only for 192.168.40.165. The other one reports "Request timed out". And if I try traceroute I can see that there is always one successful hop to the gateway (192.168.42.65) and another one either succeeds (for 192.168.40.165) or fails (for 192.168.40.147).

As I understand all ICMP packets successfully get to the server but when trying to return as soon as return address is from subnet other than 192.168.40.128/27 or 192.168.40.160/27 the resulting route will be the one of defaults. And exactly the one with the lower metric: `default 192.168.40.161 0.0.0.0 UG 99 0 0 eth1`. If I will swap metrics than only 192.168.40.147 address will be reachable from 192.168.32.69 host.

My question is if I can configure server in any way to allow both IPs reachable from my client host?

Comment: Hop up to the search box in the corner, type in "policy based routing", and you will find all the answers you desire. Works great in google too :)

Comment: If you just feel like clicking a link:  http://serverfault.com/search?q=policy+based+routing